# What is the best way to add quotes in array and pass it to mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays

i always get warning mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in....
i guess its because there are no single quotes around the array items. how would i do this? any suggestions to make this code better/smarter/safer(sql injection) and mainly working?  i'm new with this ..  thank you

this is the code "i'm getting the array from jquery with json"

```
<?php
include_once("dbconx.php");
$json = $_POST['cats'];
$json_string = stripslashes($json);
$data = json_decode($json_string, true);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
$th= "";
for($i=0; $i < count($data); $i++)
   {
   $th .= $data[$i].',';
   }
   $th = rtrim($th, ",");
     echo $th;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM themes WHERE theme IN ($th)"; 
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
}
?>
```

thanks for helping

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Comment: Use prepared statements they will escape everything for you. However you still need to validate the input

Comment: if $data is an array , you can use `implode(',' , $data);`

Comment: BTW, that's like the code most prone to SQL injection ever. You should escape your data.

Comment: Besides, it's also XSS prone... and you could do `foreach($data as $Key => $Val) {}` instead of the `for()`

Comment: thanks for the replies   yes i know its not safe code at the moment  that's why i asked how to make it safer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your `$data` is correct, instead of that `for` loop, you can just do this:

`$data = "'".implode("','",$data)."'";`

Comment: But assuming someone posts some MYSQL commands to 'cats', they can delete your entire database.

Comment: well yeah.. but the question was how to wrap some quotes around the values, not how to make his query secure.

Comment: well, apparently he updated his question. in any case, using prepared statement would solve for that anyway

Comment: hmm when i alert the $data now everything is fine  all the quotes and comma  but php gives me a warning now         implode(): Invalid arguments passed in ......  i checked before $data and its an array. what could be the problem now.  thanks anyway

Comment: @GeorgKirschstein well the only reason you would get that warning is if `$data` was NOT an array, or if it was a multi-dim array..

Comment: thanks  hmm strange its gives me the output array  when i call it with gettyp  and vardump. and itlooks like this now 'a','b','c' and when i do $data= array() before the implode its just outputs " dobbel quotes or two single quotes

Comment: @GeorgKirschstein `$data = array();` doesn't convert existing value to an array. It overwrites what was there before with an empty array. IOW, that assigns an empty array to the variable. So if you are doing that before the implode, you are overwriting whatever was in `$data` with an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the single quotes in:

```
for($i=0; $i < count($data); $i++)
{
  $th .= "'" . mysql_escape_string($data[$i]) . "',";
}
```

Also, I'm calling mysql_escape_string() on the data. This needs to be called on every bit of data that comes from outside your PHP code  that you use in a MYSQL command (for instance from POST or GET) to prevent hacking by sql injection. Or, better yet, read up on and use parameterized queries/prepared statements.